# 2 pole or single pole breaker to feed sub panel

Tags: wiring, receptacle, subpanel

I want to run wires about 70 feet to a panel that will feed a 30amp rv hook up and a 20amp receptacle. Should my feeder breaker be a 2-pole or single pole?

Comment: Does your RV require 120V or 240V?

Comment: The RV is all 120v. Just a single pole 30amp needed for the RV.

Comment: How much panelboard space do you have left in the panel you're running from, and what make and model is said panel?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you.  You can use a single pole breaker or double.  Single has potential to be cheaper.

If you don't plan on maxing out the outlet and the RV at once, you could safely go as cheap as a single pole 30A breaker 10-2 wire for the run and a 30 A panel if you can find one that small.

125A panels are pretty mass produced though, so you might find it cheaper ro get a 125A any way.  Just make sure its lugs can safely accept 10 AWG wire and know that you won't be able to use half of the positions in it.

Personally, I'd run 60A or 100A, 240 from a double pole breaker.  Especially if it's going to involve digging, since you can do more later with a full 240v panel and the extra amperage.  Think about EV charging in the next decade.

Comment: Thanks, you all have helped me to look at my project more closely to better formulate a plan. I'm now thinking I will go ahead and run 70amp using a 2p 70amp breaker. This will give me the ability to upgrade my RV hookup to 70 if ever I go with a larger rig.

Comment: will 8-3 uf work or do I need to go to a 6-3 uf?

Comment: Check my work at http://www.paigewire.com/pumpWireCalc.aspx  but I think you want awg4 for copper.  The most amps you can usually put through 8AWG is 40 or 50.  You want 70 and you want some distance.  -3 is correct

Comment: You're welcome!  Also, UF cable is one approach.  But while you're working on your plan, consider using THWN wires in a conduit if you're going to be digging so you don't have to dig twice.  You might even lay two conduits side by side and opt to use only one for now.  Conduit will protect your conductors better and allow for easier replacement or expansion at a later date (ethernet?, fiber?) THWN should be cheaper than UF, and if you ever damage it you might only have to replace the damaged conductor, not all of them since it's not bundled like UF. Leave caution tape buried above it too.

Comment: Do you have a conduit fill calculator? Or do you know what size I should use for 3-8awg and a #10 ground?

Comment: Using http://conduitfillcalculator.com/, you could do it with a 1/2 inch schedule 80 PVC conduit.  Using a bare ground would reduce fill capacity.  or you could use metal conduit for your ground.  I'd run two 1/2 inch conduits, or one 1 1/2 inch.  Two separates could be nice to isolate power from signal.  Larger is nice if you end up wanting to up the current.